# How can I disable these two warnings?

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing an application, and I received four obsolete warnings when compiling. They're irrelevant and I'd like to supress them. I know I can do that by adding the warning id to the  tag, but I don't know where I can find those IDs?

The warnings are:

> - unused local variable
> - A reference was created to embedded interop assembly 'Microsoft.mshtml' because of an indirect reference to that assembly from assembly 'AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib'. Consider changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property on either assembly. (I don't understand this one really, if someone could explain what it means actually...)

Answer (score 1):

`unused local variable` means you declared

```
Dim unusedVariable as ClassX
```

somewhere and never said

```
unusedVariable = AnInstanceOfClassX ' can be "nothing"
```

If you do

```
Dim unusedVariable as new ClassX()
```

Then it will be "used" by assigning it as a new instance of ClassX. Just figure out why you declare it and never assign to it. This has to be your call since I can't see your code.

You can remove the `A reference was created to embedded interop assembly` warning by going to your references in the solution explorer under your project (you must have "show all files" enabled in VS 2012). Locate the reference to `DHTMLEDLib`, right click, properties. In the properties window, change "Embed Interop Types" to true.

You can find out more about embedding interop types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409610.aspx)

edit: also, a warning doesn't necessarily mean there is something wrong. Learn to live with warnings in Visual Studio, to a degree

Comment: I agree, a warning is not necesarilly means something wrong, it's just Visual Studio's way to let you know where and how you could have a code better. :)